# How to make my computer think an IP is somewhere else

Tags: networking, ip, tcpip

I have a local app which code I do not own and tries to directly connect to some IP, let's say `123.45.67.890`. For testing purposes, I would like to re-route that connection to somewhere else, another completely different IP, and hex-editing the IP in the file is not an option. How would I go about this? I can't edit the hosts file and have an effect, because there's no DNS request being performed. Solutions preferably on Windows, but I can also do it under Linux.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know how (if) you can do it under Windows, but you can use IPTables on linux to rewrite a packet using DNAT

You might want to try something like

```
/sbin/iptables -I PREROUTING -d 123.45.67.89 -j DNAT --to-destination 98.76.54.32
```

Answer (score 0):

See re-routing an IP to [localhost](http://anime.myrpi.org/blog/2012/01/04/how-to-reroute-a-local-ip-address-to-localhost-127-0-0-1/).

> This method uses the netsh MS-Dos function. Specifically, you can add
>   multiple ip addresses to your loop-back adapter. Once added, Microsoft
>   handles calls to any addresses in the loop-back adapter, causing them
>   to stay (i.e. loop-back) within windows, and not route to the actual
>   IP location (Be it on your LAN or even the WAN).

Comment: And if you need to actually forward to a different host, you can combine this with a TCP proxy running on your local machine.

Comment: Hm the fact is I needed to sniff the packets using Wireshark/Netmon, and they won't sniff on the loopback interface on windows.